# Forwarding requests to localhost with Iptables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port-forwarding, iptables

I have an Ubuntu VM (in Virtualbox) and a Win11 local machine.

I would like to send HTTP requests (for example 127.0.0.1:{PORT}/api/1/) to the virtual machine. The VM has an app running that only accepts requests to localhost, so I need to send the request from local to guest, and redirect the request in the VM to its localhost. I also need to achieve this using Iptables.

I have tried a bunch of iptables commands but without any success. I am getting "request timed out" or "connrefused" errors. Meanwhile I am able to run simple python servers on both machines and I am able to curl them from both local and vm.

In my understanding I need to configure Iptables inside the VM to accept requests to its IP and some port, but forward them to localhost and the needed port. But I struggle to implement this anyway.

I've tried variations of this command, but I believe this is closer to how it should look like (first I enable port forwarding):

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 
127.0.0.1:4040
```

In my understanding if now I send a request from my host like this, then the vm should receive this request and re-route it to its localhost port 4040, and I should receive the response from API: curl 172.20.10.4:80/api/v1/... But nothing happens, I get "request timed out". If I curl the "172.20.10.4:80", nothing happens too

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If it’s HTTP you want, why not use a reverse proxy? There’s plenty of (more or less) specialized solutions available (HAProxy, Traefik, Caddy, …) and some “normal” web servers can do it too (nginx, Apache httpd, …).

Comment: @DanielB I am actually trying to recreate one scenario where a customer at work uses iptables to forward requests, but gets errors in the app (not related to my question)

Comment: Ah, okay. In that case, it would be very helpful what those ”bunch of iptables” commands were, to see what you tried and maybe also what’s missing. You can probably retrieve them from `history`.

Comment: @DanielB Basically I've tried variations of this command, but I believe this is closer to how it should look like (first I enable port forwarding):

sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:4040

In my understanding if now I send a request from my host like this, then the vm should receive this request and re-route it to its localhost port 4040, and I should receive the response from API:

curl 172.20.10.4:80/api/v1/...

But nothing happens, I get "request timed out". If I curl the "172.20.10.4:80", nothing happens too

Answer (score 0):

`PREROUTING` will take care of packets coming in.

You also have to handle packets going out with `POSTROUTING`.

Here's something that might work that is adapted from my `iptables` script - replace variables accordingly.  (`$I` is just `/sbin/iptables`)

```
  "$I" -A PREROUTING -t nat \
   --protocol "$PROTOCOL" \
   --destination-port "$OUTSIDE_PORT" \
    --jump DNAT --to-destination "127.0.0.1:$INSIDE_PORT"

  "$I" -A POSTROUTING -t nat \
   --protocol "$PROTOCOL" \
   --source "$INSIDE_IP" --source-port "$INSIDE_PORT" \
    --jump SNAT --to-source "$VM_EXTERNAL_IP"
```